# Controlling the position of geom_text labels in a bar plot with positive and negative values and facets with different scales

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want labels to appear outside of both positive and negative bars, so I can't simply use hjust to move the location.  Right now I have this, which is close...

```
score <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "X")
group1 <- c(0,0,5,-0.2,-4.9,0)
group2 <- c(0.1,0,-1.2,0.4,0.6,0.1)
group3 <- c(0.1,0,3.4,2.9,-6.4,0)
group4 <-c(0,0,-0.9,-0.3,1.3,0)

data <- data.frame(score=as.factor(score), Group1=group1, Group2=group2, Group3=group3, Group4=group4)

data_long <- pivot_longer(data, c(Group1, Group2, Group3, Group4))
data_long$label <- paste(round(data_long$value,1),"%",sep="")
data_long$value <- data_long$value/100

sig <- rep(0, 24)
sig[c(3, 9, 11, 15, 17, 19)] <- 1
sig <- as.factor(sig)
data_long <- cbind(data_long, sig)


bars <- data_long %>% filter(score != 2,
                             score != "X") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y=name, fill=sig))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey", "firebrick")) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = ~ c(-1, 1) * max(abs(.x)),
                     labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_wrap(~score, scales = "free_x") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  geom_text(aes(label=label,
                x = value + (0.005 * sign(value))),  size = 3) +
  labs(x = "Deviation From Expected Value",
       y = "Group",
       title = "Deviations From Expected Value by Score",
       caption = "Red bars statistically significant")

print(bars)
```

This produces the following chart
[image]

But notice how in the top left facet, where the scale is REALLY small, the labels are very far removed from the non-zero bars.  I'm assuming this is because the multiplicative factor I use in the geom_text x aesthetic is large for that scale.  I took a stab at some sort of function in there that took the limits into account but I got an error

```
Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): x = ~(value + (0.005 * max(abs(.x)) * sign(value)))
```

Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hjust` as an aesthetic mapping. If you set it to `0.5 - sign(value)/2` it will be 0 for the positive bars and 1 for the negative bars, as desired.

```r
data_long %>% filter(score != 2,
                             score != "X") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y=name, fill=sig))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey", "firebrick")) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = ~ c(-1, 1) * max(abs(.x)),
                     labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_wrap(~score, scales = "free_x") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  geom_text(aes(label=label,
                x = value, hjust = 0.5 - sign(value)/2),  size = 3) +
  labs(x = "Deviation From Expected Value",
       y = "Group",
       title = "Deviations From Expected Value by Score",
       caption = "Red bars statistically significant")
```

[image]